# sIFR doesn't apply to children in list

Tags: javascript, css, sifr

I am unable to remove bullets in nested unordered lists after sIFR has been applied. I experinced this on a website I was creating.

I tried to create a basic HTML skeleton and apply the sIFR to easily figure out how to remove child bullets, but it didn't work here either.

```
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Option 2-1</li>
            <li>Option 2-2
                <ul>
                    <li>Option 2-2-1</li>
                    <li>Option 2-2-2</li>
                    <li>Option 2-2-3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li>Option 2-3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I seem to be unable to reference the inner ul's in any way. I've tried several selectors, including:

```
sIFR.replace(infinityt, {
  selector: 'li',
  css: ['.sIFR-root { list-style-type: none; list-style: none;  }', 'ul { list-style-type: none; list-style:none; }' ]
});

sIFR.replace(infinityt, {
  selector: '#menu',
  css: ['.sIFR-root { list-style-type: none; list-style: none; margin: 300px; }' ]
});
```

Comment: sIFR is antiquated; http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/

Comment: I agree sIFR is not the best. Though the font used doesnt render all that nice in IE as webfont, so I have been asked to use sIFR instead. Which now gives all kinds of headaches :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by wrapping the text in a span and sIFR the span. Normal CSS can then be used to remove bullets in the list.

```
    <ul>
        <li><span><a href="#">Option 1</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Option 2</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="#">Option 2-1</a></span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting more specific on the CSS?

Like if the li's are being styled by a parent element, then you have to include that parent element in the CSS declaration to override it -
and you could have been trying to attack the style by itself I think.
Try something like:
parent child child child style{}

or whatever it needs to overwrite it.

Comment: That seemed like a good approach, but I couldn't get it to work either. I have published my test here, http://skill.dk/sifr/testofsirfr.html
Thanks for the suggestion though.